# How to prevent Gmail from logging in when I am in private session?

Tags: firefox, login, gmail

I use Firefox in the private mode because I use a public computer. This I thought would eliminate all cookies, history and passwords between sessions. But I am finding, time and again, that Gmail does not ask me for my password when I restart my browser; it automatically logs me in.

What's up with that?

How can I make sure that Google plays fair and forgets my login credentials after I close my browser?

Note: I do not check "remember me" as I login.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/26689/how-do-i-tell-firefox-to-only-keep-persistent-cookies-from-sites-i-want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have Firefox automatically destroy your cookies and history at the end of every "browsing session", if that's what you're looking for. There are also a few add-ons that allow for the easy management of cookies on a site-by-site basis, such as CookieSafe or CookieCuller.

Comment: Yes! I thought that was done automatically. How do I configure the browser to destroy all cookies when I close it?

Comment: +1 for cookie culler, excellent add-on

Comment: @picardo Go to Tools -> Options -> Privacy, check "Clear History when Firefox Closes", and click the "Settings" button next to that, and check everything.

Answer (score 3):

If you go into the Firefox options and then the Privacy tab, there should be a dropdown for how long to keep cookies. By default it is set to "*until they expire*", you can change this to "*until I close Firefox*".

You may also want to check the box just below there to "Clear history when Firefox closes".