# In Firefox, how can I implement a deletion policy for cookies based on their domain?

Tags: firefox, cookies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I tell Firefox to only keep persistent cookies from sites I want?](https://superuser.com/questions/26689/how-do-i-tell-firefox-to-only-keep-persistent-cookies-from-sites-i-want)

I can deny cookies and allow some domains. I can delete cookies when they expire, or when I close Firefox. What I want to do:

- Generally accept cookies
- For all domains on my "exceptions" list (which I'm not using to allow / deny a cookie), keep cookies until they expire
- For all other domains, delete cookies when I close Firefox, or maybe when I "Clear private data"

It seems this can not be done via the standard settings. But can I hack some config, get some plugin, etc.?

Comment: You could use Opera ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the add-on [CookieSafe](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2497):

> This extension will allow you to
>   easily control cookie permissions. It
>   will appear on your statusbar. Just
>   click on the icon to allow, block, or
>   temporarily allow the site to set
>   cookies. You can also view or clear
>   the cookies and exceptions by...

Please note that the CookieSafe icon has two menus, that you reach by right-click and left-click.
 CookieSafe is very complete in its capabilities.

Comment: Looks pretty complete, almost too much stuff. Thanks.