# Clear cookies with whitelisting some?

Tags: firefox, privacy, cookies

Firefox (4) allows me to [`Accept cookies from sites`](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Options%20window%20-%20Privacy%20panel?as=u#w_use-custom-settings-for-history) (with `Exceptions` to Allow or Deny for some). However, as far as I can see, it ain't possible to use the option `Keep until: I close Firefox` and still keep *some* cookies when I close.

Is it somehow possible to keep only a whitelist of cookies and clear all the rest on close?

*Does this even make sense*, or should I just make a whitelist of cookies and keep those regardless of closing Firefox?

Comment: It does make sense, I do not know how to do it.

Comment: Ah, I found the duplicate to my question: [How do I tell Firefox to only keep persistent cookies from sites I want?](http://superuser.com/questions/26689/how-do-i-tell-firefox-to-only-keep-persistent-cookies-from-sites-i-want)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the master setting for your cookies is "until I close Firefox" I think that sites you whitelist will get to keep cookies after you close the browser.

Comment: This is in fact correct. I have just tried it with my FF 4.0.1. (Note that `Clear History when Firefox closes` is not checked, only `Until I close` for cookies.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround that may generate some errors. Set the permissions for the folders that the sites you want to keep to removing the delete permission for your user. This way, firefox will not be able to delete them (ever). This might cause problems.