# How to know which cookies are associated to a specific website?

Tags: firefox, browser, cookies

I am using Firefox, but it could apply to all desktop-based browser (similar but different I think to [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/26689/how-do-i-tell-firefox-to-only-keep-persistent-cookies-from-sites-i-want)).

I am having issues logging to a specific website. All things being equals, only by enabling all first party cookies am I able to successfully accessing my account on the website. Usually, I block all cookies by default and manually white-list websites that I trust and it works well.

But, for this website specifically, adding the domain name to my white list is not enough; surely there are more than one domain name involved (it is my Microsoft account, if it helps).

Is there some way to know all the cookies used by a website (not only the ones with a name directly associated) in order to white list them all?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

1. Close all browser sessions.
2. Temporarily allow **all** cookies.
3. Login to the desired site.
4. Look at all the cookies that were created and whitelist those.
5. Disable all cookies again.