# Firefox: Clear all cookies on exit except whitelisted (without addons)

Tags: firefox, cookies

Identical to an [old question from 2009](https://superuser.com/questions/26689/how-do-i-tell-firefox-to-only-keep-persistent-cookies-from-sites-i-want)

Upon exit, I want Firefox to clear *all* cookies except those set by (for example) `wikipedia.org`. Also, firefox should allow all sites to set cookies when running.

Is this possible with just the default settings/options without installing any addons? No matter which way I try, firefox either clears all cookies or none on exit.

I'm asking for recent versions of Firefox, specifically FF51 running on Windows 10 if it makes any difference.

Answer (score -1):

here's where you set cookie options.
[**about:config**](http://about:config)

[image]

<s>But selective delete on exit requires an addon such as
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selectivecookiedelete/</s>

Update

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?platform=windows&q=selectivecookiedelete

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: sorry @DavidPostill I meant to say ,  it shows that it is not possible without an addon

Comment: Addon link is dead.

Comment: @OJFord updated

Comment: This attempts  to show non addon preferences for cookie handling and addons too

Answer (score -1):

You can do this (see screenshots of Firefox Options)
[Clear cookies when closing Firefox](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxIpLQgORVf9NU5teG1ob0RSNjQ)

You can whitelist your trusted sites using Exceptions
[Whitelist trusted sites](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxIpLQgORVf9LUJDVWtXUkFQRlE)
enter image description here

If you want to sync these settings across Firefox on different devices you can use a Firefox account (I can't add the 3rd link as I'm newbie on this site).

==============

Following earlier problems with unexpected cookies remaining in the Firefox browser I have retested on 2 Windows 10 machines.
One using Firefox beta (55.0b13) and Firefox (55.0b13) developer edition.
In both cases they cleared unwanted cookies from the browser after closing all the tabs and then
restarting the browser.
Sites specified in the Exceptions - cookies kept their cookies.

Given I had problems with Win 7 and Firefox 54 before it shows you need to check your browser cookies periodically
to ensure things are working normally.

I had less success syncing exceptions (i.e. the list of sites that are allowed to keep cookies).
However, that is probably down to my lack of experience with this feature.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this doesn't work: Can someone confirm? I've tried it with FF54 on *buntu.

Comment: Thanks for spotting this.  I need to do more testing I checked my browser FF54.0.1 on Win 7 and there were lots of cookies that should have been cleared by when Firefox was closed previously.  However, when I logged out of FF sync and restarted FF the cookies disappeared